# Ahk2Exe This line does not contain a recognized action

Tags: key, autohotkey, auto

this error when I try to compile my auto hot key(ahk) code.
Ahk2Exe Error  Error: The script contains syntax errors.

Specifically:
C:\Users\ibraheem\Downloads\e.ahk (1) : ==> This line does not contain a recognized action.
Specifically: #SingleInstance, force

the code:

```
#SingleInstance, force
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
RCtrl:: 
    Toggle := !Toggle
    while Toggle
    {
        Send e
        Sleep, 300 ; 0.3 Seconds
    }
Return


F11::ExitApp  ; exit
```

Comment: No error here. Copy the above code in a new script from here and compile it. Maybe your script contains encrypted or other invisible characters.